# How to get variables out of closure?

Tags: javascript

I have this class/service:

```
var User = (function () {
'use strict';

var user;

function set( user ) {
    user = user;
}

function getVotes() {
    return user.votes;
}

return {
    user     : user,
    set      : set,
    getVotes : getVotes
};

}());
```

I store the user like so: `User.set( user );`
but when i try and retrieve the user with `User.user` or get the users votes with `User.getVotes()` I get undefined. 
Why is that and is there a better way?

Comment: Setting `user:user` doesn't capture the closure. Only functions capture closures. Variable/property assignment assigns values.

Comment: ahhh I see. Thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different name for the setter methods parameter. Since you have used the name `user` for both the closure variable and the parameter inside the setter method when referring `user` it will only refer to the parameter not the closure item.

The assignment operation does not do anything as it is assigning the value of a variable to itself

```js
var User = (function() {
  'use strict';

  var user;

  function set(usr) {
    user = usr;
  }

  function getVotes() {
    return user.votes;
  }

  return {
    user: user,
    set: set,
    getVotes: getVotes
  };

}());

User.set({
  name: 'x',
  votes: 5
});

snippet.log('votes: ' + User.getVotes())
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: well that explains that xD

Comment: Just i am asking just for  information is it Singleton pattern?

Comment: Yes, well my services like this are at least.